# COGNOS 11 Concatenate with cast for char length

Tags: casting, varchar, cognos

Probably simple but my head is fried right now with figures. I'm  using COGNOS 11 and trying to make a data item display character length of '4' i.e 0014 rather than just 14. I can do this in the edit within  the report properties but I'm trying to do a concatenate string and it keeps reverting to 14.

I've been trying CAST([Demand No], varchar(4)) as the expression definition (comes up as 'No error') but it still keeps dropping the leading 00 on the report.

My full concatenated string so far [Unit ID]||to_char(cast([Demand Date],date), 'ddmmyyyy')||cast([Demand No], varchar(4)). This produces XXXXXXDDMMYYYY0000 but only when the last four characters are 0000 but it looks like this XXXXXXDDMMYYYY00 if the leading 0's are dropped.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try lpad(cast([Demand No], varchar(4)),2,'0')

Comment: Is `lpad` a Cognos function, or would it require the package to be configured to include functions for Informix or Oracle?

Comment: I use SQL Server.  Using `lpad` in a report that uses the GO Sales (query) package returns `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 'lpad' is not a recognized built-in function name.`  So, clearly, Cognos is not translating `lpad` into something SQL Server can understand.

Comment: The original post had to_char which made me assume Oracle,  you'll need to check the vendor specific functions of the database type being used to see what is available.  For MSSQL you would use the right and left functions.  The following link provides some good examples  https://database.guide/left-padding-in-sql-server-3-lpad-equivalents/

Comment: As Dougp commented, maybe you need to configure the package to include the SQL native functions so you can use LPAD().
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.doc/t_selectfunctionsets.html

Comment: ...or use only functions that Cognos understands natively, so the code is portable across RDBMSs.  In fact, if you try to use LPAD against SQL Server, you will get an error message regardless of which vendor function set is included in the package.  Cognos simply doesn't know how to translate LPAD into something SQL Server will understand.  I assume that's true when using other RDBMSs aside from Informix and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but this uses generic Cognos functions:

```
substring('0000', 1, 4 - char_length(cast([Demand No], varchar(4)))) || cast([Demand No], varchar(4))
```

Comment: Ok we got there with lpad(cast([Demand No], varchar(4)),2,'0'), just had to change the 2 for a 4. 

Thank you for the help, much appreciated.